# HTML code - displaying pictures as in a slide show

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slideshow, slide

In the attached HTML code that I’ve found on the web to display pictures one-at-a-time every 5 sec with a fade-in/fade-out effect.
The only issue is that at the very beginning all pictures are shown at once and only after the first cycle is completed it performs as expected.
Can anybody advise how to modify the code such that it performs as expected since the beginning?
Thanks.

```js
/* Slide show - Start */
var images = document.getElementById("image-container").children;
var index = 0;

function fadeImages() {
  var nextIndex = (index + 1) % images.length;
  var currentImage = images[index];
  var nextImage = images[nextIndex];

  currentImage.style.opacity = 1;

  var opacity = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    opacity += 0.05;
    nextImage.style.opacity = opacity;
    currentImage.style.opacity = 1 - opacity;
    if (opacity >= 1) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      currentImage.style.display = "none";
      nextImage.style.display = "block";
      index = nextIndex;
      setTimeout(fadeImages, 5000);
    }
  }, 50);
}

fadeImages();
/* Slide show - END */
```

```css
#image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#image-container imgfirst-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- Comment -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="image-container">
      <img src="image1.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" alt="Image 1">
      <img src="image2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" alt="Image 2">
      <img src="image3.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" alt="Image 3">
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first spot some issues:

- There's no pleasant cross-fade effect
- inline HTML `style` attribute should be avoided for the rare cases when it's really necessary or logic
- The CSS is missing `:` all over the place
- The `imgfirst-child` is not a valid selector
- Avoid hardcoding IDs in JavaScript - such will force you to copy/paste code in order to have multiple slideshows in a single page. Use classes selectors instead. Create a JS class or a function for your slideshow/s
- Use an active CSS class like `.is-active` in order to set the styles for the visible image/slide
- Use `clearInterval` to allow users to pause the slideshow to enjoy the slide they're hovering

Let's start with removing IDs and using classes instead. Now you can have even multiple

```html
My cats:
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/800/587" alt="Image a 1">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/220" alt="Image a 2">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/287" alt="Image a 3">
</div>

Some more cats:
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="Image b 1">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/360/300" alt="Image b 2">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Image b 3">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/460" alt="Image b 4">
</div>
```

Let's hide all images and use that `.is-active` styles.
Remember that if you have `position: absolute;` children, a parent is better defined also with a `position` other than `static`. We'll use `relative`:

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;   /* anything other than the default static */
  height: 160px;        /* make the parent dictate the height */
}

.image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;  /* or use: contain; to make the entire image visible */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;  /* Prevent mouse actions */
}

.image-container img.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;  /* Allow mouse actions */
}
```

Now for the JavaScript part.
Since we have multiple sliders in one page, you could either create a `Class`, instantiate it passing a desired container ID or simply pass the container Element to your `fadeImages(elParent)` function.
See how cleaner and simpler the JS is now:

```js
const fadeImages = (elContainer) => {

  const duration = 3000;
  const elsSlides = elContainer.children;
  const tot = elsSlides.length;
  let idx = 0;
  let itv = null;
  
  const hide = () => elsSlides[idx].classList.remove("is-active");
  const show = () => elsSlides[idx].classList.add("is-active"); 
  const anim = () => {
    hide();
    idx = (idx + 1) % tot;
    show();
  };
  const play = () => itv = setInterval(anim, duration);
  const stop = () => clearInterval(itv);
  
  // Start!
  elContainer.addEventListener("pointerenter", stop);
  show();
  play();
}

// Init!
document.querySelectorAll(".image-container").forEach(fadeImages);
```

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 160px;
}
.image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none; /* Prevent mouse actions */
}

.image-container img.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
My cats:
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/800/587" alt="Image a 1">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/220" alt="Image a 2">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/287" alt="Image a 3">
</div>
Some more cats:
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/500/300" alt="Image b 1">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/360/300" alt="Image b 2">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Image b 3">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/460" alt="Image b 4">
</div>
```

and every slideshow (carousel) runs independently from each other.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var images = document.getElementById("image-container").children;
let i = images.length-1;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  //increase opacity of current image
  if(images[i].style.opacity){
    images[i].style.opacity-=1/50;
  } else images[i].style.opacity = 1.0;
  //if current image invisble then works with next
  if(images[i].style.opacity<=0)i--;
  //if last then stop interval
  if(i==-1)clearInterval(interval)
},50);
```

```css
img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Comment -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="image-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/800/587" alt="Image a 1">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/220" alt="Image a 2">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/400/287" alt="Image a 3">
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just tried simplify this task, maybe will be usefull
*thx roko-c-buljan for cats source

Comment: Never use `opacity` or some other `style` property as a *truth of state*, use index instead. Why do you use `-=1/50`?  `let i = images.length-1;` why would you want to set `i` to the wrong slide initially? a counter is best initially set to `0` as it should be (unless changed by the user in which case modulo should be used to fix other related problems). Why use ID? Limiting a piece of JavaScript to one specific element in the page limits reusability and the *DRY* principles. (⏎)

Comment: Why the interval set at `50ms`? Why stop the slideshow at all? Would you ever want to implement your own suggestion in a live project and see a carousel suddenly ending in nothingness (blank surface)? Clearly not. Please, revise some UI, UX best practices, revise JavaScript best practices. PS: you're welcome for the cats source (not my project, but a funky one indeed) ;)

Comment: if opacity exist then use it, if not then create:) 1/50 - just speed(check interval speed), you feel free to change proportions... counting from the end  - because i use something like a "stack" method. ID - because in question he/she/it/they is using id, i just not have changed it. really it is not have a serious meaning but also if you want a cycle or maybe something else please feel free to ad it :D cats are awesome

Answer (score -1):

Have all images apart from the first be hidden:

```css
#image-container img {
  position absolute;
  transition opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#image-container img:not(:first-child) {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```js
/* Slide show - Start */
var images = document.getElementById("image-container").children;
var index = 0;

function fadeImages() {
  var nextIndex = (index + 1) % images.length;
  var currentImage = images[index];
  var nextImage = images[nextIndex];

  currentImage.style.opacity = 1;

  var opacity = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    opacity += 0.05;
    nextImage.style.opacity = opacity;
    currentImage.style.opacity = 1 - opacity;
    if (opacity >= 1) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      currentImage.style.display = "none";
      nextImage.style.display = "block";
      index = nextIndex;
      setTimeout(fadeImages, 5000);
    }
  }, 50);
}
fadeImages();
```

```css
#image-container img {
  position absolute;
  transition opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#image-container img:not(:first-child) {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" alt="Image 1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" alt="Image 2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?0" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" alt="Image 3">
</div>
```

Comment: Great solutions, I would probably add a timeout on the initial call, to avoid the first image only being shown 1s compared to the 5s the rest is looping through.

Comment: Yes, I would too. I did not do that in this case since it seemed out-of-scope to the original question.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.